# How can I use NTLM authentication in a Delphi SOAP Web Service client?

Tags: web-services, delphi, soap, ntlm, indy

For a Microsoft CRM project, we need [NTLM authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTLM) in the Delphi 2009 web service client.

It looks like [Indy 10 Tiburon already has experimental NTLM support](http://www.delphipraxis.net/topic157784.html).

How can I activate the NTLM authentication for the THTTPRio component and use the logon information (user name, password, domain) of the destination web service server?

Edit: it would also be helpful if there is a way to use other authentication methods than 'Basic', for example [HTTP Digest access authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the user name property of the WebNode subcomponent of the THTTPRio component, use the domain name followed by a backslash and the user name:

**'domain\username'**

After entering the WSDL URL at designtime, the HTTPRIO component will list available port and services.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understand your question - activate NTLM authentication? If you're looking for NTLM API imports for Delphi, you can find those in the JEDI Windows Security Library on the [JEDI API home page](http://jedi-apilib.sourceforge.net/). If the plan is to see how to use it, I'd say [MSDN is your friend](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378749%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I have modified the texte: How can I activate the NTLM authentication for the THTTPRio component. The NTLM API imports are there and also a IdAuthenticateNTLM.pas. If the only way is to modify the Delphi HTTPRio / HTTPSoap classes, to use the NTLM API, integration of the CRM web service would be easier done in C# (or even Java) with an additional message exchange layer.