# how to connect microsoft crm with delphi?

Tags: .net, web-services, delphi

i want connect to microsoft crm with delphi 7 or 2007

wsdl = http://crm/mscrmservices/2007/crmservice.asmx

my code

```
  token := CrmAuthenticationToken.Create;
  token.OrganizationName := 'test';
  token.AuthenticationType := 0;
  service := GetCrmServiceSoap();
  customer := contact3.Create;
  customer.salutation := 'test';
  customer.lastname := 'test';
  customer.jobtitle := 'test';
  customer.telephone1 := 'test';
  customer.emailaddress1 := 'test';
  gid := service.Create(customer);
  showmessage(gid);
```

the service ask username & password and i'm typing my domain username & password but don't work and service ask agian?
when i cancel dialog for username & password I'm getting this error message "401 Unauthorized"
please help me

Answer (score 0):

Use '**domain\username**' as the username property in the HTTPRio component.

See: [How can I use NTLM authentication in a Delphi SOAP Web Service client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068452/how-can-i-use-ntlm-authentication-in-a-delphi-soap-web-service-client/1081582#1081582)